# Check whether multiple project is selected or not

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am new to eclipse plugin development. I wrote a code which gets selected project name & path. But if multiple project is selected, it lists the first one.

Here is my code

```
IStructuredSelection selection = (IStructuredSelection) window.getSelectionService().getSelection();
Object firstElement = selection.getFirstElement();
if (firstElement != null) {
    if (firstElement instanceof IAdaptable) {
        IProject project = (IProject) ((IAdaptable) firstElement).getAdapter(IProject.class);
        IPath path = project.getFullPath();
        IPath location = project.getLocation();
    }
}
```

How can I check whether multiple project is selected or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `selection.iterator` and iterate over selected items. It could be something like this!

```
    Iterator it = selection.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()){
    Object firstElement = it.next();
if (firstElement != null) {
    if (firstElement instanceof IAdaptable) {
        IProject project = (IProject) ((IAdaptable) firstElement).getAdapter(IProject.class);
        IPath path = project.getFullPath();
        IPath location = project.getLocation();
    }
}
    }
```

EDIT: Updated with more detailed code

Incorporate your logic to see whether singlr or multiple projects are selected. Use counter to check how many projects selected.

Comment: it results in an infinite loop

Comment: You can look over the size of iterator(it) and conclude it. Hope you are checking with "instanceOf IAdaptable" to see whether multiple projects has selected.

Comment: You have to call 'it.next()' in the loop to move to each new item.